# A react example from documentation is showing overloading error

Tags: reactjs, overloading

We just started a project in React, and I am so new to it.
Long in short, we want to lay the components in our webpage in a responsive way. So I was just trying the [following example](https://mui.com/components/grid/#responsive-values) from reacts documentation, and it keeps throwing the following error that honestly I couldn't understand:

```
No overload matches this call.
  Overload 1 of 2, '(props: { component: ElementType<any>; } & { alignContent?: GridContentAlignment | undefined; alignItems?: GridItemsAlignment | undefined; ... 13 more ...; zeroMinWidth?: boolean | undefined; } & CommonProps<...> & Pick<...>): Element', gave the following error.
    Type '{ xs: number; md: number; }' is not assignable to type 'GridSpacing | undefined'.
      Type '{ xs: number; md: number; }' is not assignable to type '9'.
  Overload 2 of 2, '(props: DefaultComponentProps<GridTypeMap<{}, "div">>): Element', gave the following error.
    Type '{ xs: number; md: number; }' is not assignable to type 'GridSpacing | undefined'.
      Type '{ xs: number; md: number; }' is not assignable to type '9'.ts(2769)
Grid.d.ts(141, 5): The expected type comes from property 'spacing' which is declared here on type 'IntrinsicAttributes & { component: ElementType<any>; } & { alignContent?: GridContentAlignment | undefined; alignItems?: GridItemsAlignment | undefined; ... 13 more ...; zeroMinWidth?: boolean | undefined; } & CommonProps<...> & Pick<...>'
Grid.d.ts(141, 5): The expected type comes from property 'spacing' which is declared here on type 'IntrinsicAttributes & { alignContent?: GridContentAlignment | undefined; alignItems?: GridItemsAlignment | undefined; ... 13 more ...; zeroMinWidth?: boolean | undefined; } & CommonProps<...> & Pick<...>'
(JSX attribute) spacing?: GridSpacing | undefined
Defines the space between the type item component. It can only be used on a type container component.
```

Obviously the chunk of code that is causing the error is this

```
spacing={{ xs: 2, md: 3 }}
```

I know this might be so simple to experts, but as I mentioned I just started learning React.
What is the solution, so I an apply the example without any errors?

**Edit: Added the full code**

```
import { Box, Grid, Paper, styled } from '@material-ui/core';

const Item = styled(Paper)(({ theme }) => ({
    ...theme.typography.body2,
    padding: theme.spacing(2),
    textAlign: 'center',
    color: theme.palette.text.secondary,
}));

function App() {
    return (
        <Box sx={{ flexGrow: 1 }}>
            <Grid container spacing={{ xs: 2, md: 3 }} columns={{ xs: 4, sm: 8, md: 12 }}>
                {Array.from(Array(6)).map((_, index) => (
                    <Grid item xs={2} sm={4} md={4} key={index}>
                        <Item>xs=2</Item>
                    </Grid>
                ))}
            </Grid>
        </Box>
    );
}

export default App;
```

Comment: Paste your full component, that would help.

Comment: @CyberMessiah Thanks for mentioning that. I just pasted it.

Answer (score 0):

I guess you are using it NOT on container element. Better paste the code to verify that. Just take a note at the last line in the message of the error.

> Defines the space between the type item component. It can only be used on a type container component.

Comment: Actually, I just pasted the documentation example EXACTLY as it is, and yet it didn't work .. I will try applying it on a container element as you mentioned ..